# PS scripting - Artboards saveAs

Tags: photoshop-scripting

I'm trying to write a script that rename and export several artboards based on user input given in a dialog. The script works for the renaming part, but exporting doesn't work.

I tried several options, but I can't come up with something valid... So my question is: how can I write the script for it to identify the artboards and export them based on their

Here's my functions

```
// Is it an artboard?
function isArtBoard()
{
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Lyr "), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));
    return executeActionGet(ref).getBoolean(stringIDToTypeID("artboardEnabled"));
};
// end of isArtBoard()
```

This is the saveJPG

```
 // SaveJPG function

function SaveJPG(fileName, teamName, componentName) {
  var quality = 8;
  var filePath = app.activeDocument.path;
    filePath = filePath.toString().split('/');
    filePath = filePath.splice(0,filePath.length-2);
    filePath = filePath.join('/');
  var fileDestination = new File (filename + ".jpeg");
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = quality; //1-12
  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length ; i++)
  {
    doc.activeLayer = layers[i];
    if (isArtBoard()) //checking if artboard because there could be a group or a normal layer on a top level
    {
      doc.activeLayer.saveAs(fileDestination, jpgSaveOptions, true,Extension.LOWERCASE);
    }
  }
}

// end SaveJPG
```

Comment: first you should change new File (filename + ".jpeg"); to new File (filePath + "/" + filename + ".jpeg"); because the file method must be new File(path).